# Are all independent clauses sentences?

Tags: independent-clauses, compound-sentences

> She went to the doctor; she felt sick.

I understand that independent clauses can stand alone as sentences. But, would it be incorrect to say that an independent clause is not a sentence because it's part of a compound sentence?  For instance in the example above, are both clauses not sentences? Or are they each a sentence that makes up a compound sentence?

Comment: The exact definition of the term 'sentence' has never been standardised: formal and functional definitions exist. These would lead to the answers 'no' and 'yes' respectively.

Comment: I'd define an independent clause as one that is not dependent on any other element in the sentence and thus can (typically) stand alone as a sentence.

Answer (score 1):

All independent clauses are sentences on their own.

According to traditional grammar, independent clauses are also called [*main clauses*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_clause).

> An **independent clause** (or **main clause**) is a clause that can stand by itself as a simple sentence. An independent clause contains a subject and a predicate and makes sense by itself.

And a [*main clause*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/main_clause) (or an independent clause) is always a sentences on its own because it always has at its center a predicate.

> A clause that can form a complete sentence standing alone, having a
>   subject and a predicate.

Comment: You might need to go stronger than *can* to establish the point. Just because it can doesn't mean it (always) does.

Comment: Would you say that someone who calls 'She went to the doctor; she felt sick.' a sentence is wrong?